# Visual Studio 2017 Community always crashes when creating dataset for table

Tags: visual-studio, dataset

When I create a new project, add a database, create a table for that database and then try to create a dataset with that table, Visual Studio always crashes. I then get the option to start a debugger, which tells me

> Unhandled exception at 0x01191242 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0x00050DC8.

When I create an empty dataset without selecting a table, Visual Studio doesn't crash.

My Visual Studio version is 15.3.5.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: run as administrator? update? [report a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search.html?f=&type=question+OR+problem+OR+problem&type=question+OR+problem+OR+problem&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=Access+violation+writing+location+create+table+dataset)?

Comment: I did! It's the current version! I did!